# Java servlet creating tmp files

Tags: java, servlets

I have a Java servlet that uploads files, but when I upload the same file twice the applet creates a `.tmp` file. How can I make it stop doing that?

Comment: please add proper details to make your question answerable

Comment: my servlet use the apache commons librery to upload a file with multipart request. but when i want to upload the same file uploaded before the servlet upload a file .tmp how can i made a control about this?

Comment: @saimon please update the question and don't use comments to add more details on the question

Comment: @Saimon In the text of your question: include more information about your setup: Apache, your use-case, etc.  Then include some of the following: your code, error logs (do you get any?), what have you tried? Have you tried simple solutions: using if-logic to first check if files have the same name and renaming them if they do? What do you think the answer will look like?

Answer (score 0):

Append a random sequence to the string, seperated by a value such as `-`

Then once the file is ready for download, strip the random sequence.

Comment: append to the fileName do u mean?

Comment: yes, sorry. orignalfilename = blah.txt gets transformed into blah-56545645.txt